# Switch between anaconda and miniconda (miniforge)

Tags: python-2.7, miniconda, anaconda3

I have installed conda using miniforge. Since my mac has a m1 chip, i had to install conda using `Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh`, inorder to get tensorflow working. unfortunately this version (minforge/minconda arm64) doesn't have python2 for some reason. As I require python2 for another project (doesnot require tensorflow) I have decided to install anaconda3.

But now I am unaware how to switch between the two conda versions (anaconda3 and miniconda/miniforge3).

For example when I enter `activate conda` in the terminal, it activates the `base` environment of the miniforge version.
How do I activate `base` environment of the anaconda version. So that I can create python2 environment there (anaconda3).

Comment: I have a very similar situation whereby I need to have just miniforge but with the ability to tweak it to install the packages I want including non-arm versions or a way to have anaconda3 AND miniforge coexist on my mac. Did you figure out a solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-conda-on-an-m1-mac-b2df5608a141), one solution is to change the content of your .zshrc file, save your changes, close and reopen your terminal. I tested on a MacBook Pro M1 where Miniforge3 and Anaconda3 are currently installed and it works. In the following, just replace --PATH-- with the path of the requested environment management system. For example, I replace --PATH-- with opt/anaconda3 for Anaconda3 and miniforge3 for .. Miniforge3.

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/username/--PATH--/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/username/--PATH--/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/username/--PATH--/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/username/--PATH--/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now i encounter the same issue, but can you explain which path. every answer is talking about path, is that Export Path that I need to change? and where to change ?

Comment: Open your .zshrc file with a text editor, locate the conda section that starts with `# >>> conda initialize >>>`, then for the next 4 lines : `__conda_setup="$('/Users/username/--PATH--/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"` | `if [ -f "/Users/username/--PATH--/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then` | `. "/Users/username/--PATH--/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"` | `export PATH="/Users/username/--PATH--/bin:$PATH"` | replace --PATH-- with `opt/anaconda3` or `miniforge3` to enable anaconda or miniforge, respectively.

Answer (score 5):

A quick fix for switching between environments is to pick out the path you get from the output of `conda env list`. Here is what I get from both miniforge and miniconda:

```
(base) user@machine script % conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/user/miniforge3
nmgp                     /Users/user/miniforge3/envs/nmgp
scphere                  /Users/user/miniforge3/envs/scphere
                     /opt/miniconda3
                     /opt/miniconda3/envs/gpcounts
                     /opt/miniconda3/envs/gpy
                     /opt/miniconda3/envs/test
                     /opt/miniconda3/envs/nmgp
                     /opt/miniconda3/envs/scphere
                     /opt/miniconda3/envs/ssdgp
```

To activate the miniforge environments you can use the name directly:

```
conda activate nmgp
```

To activate a miniconda environment you can use the absolute path:

```
conda activate /opt/miniconda3/envs/nmgp
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @manciacci 's answer,
Change the existing .zshrc like below you only have to change `CONDA_PATH` in your .zshrc file. After that, you may have to do `conda activate` in a new shell.

```
CONDA_PATH_1=miniconda3
CONDA_PATH_2=miniforge3
CONDA_PATH=${CONDA_PATH_1}
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/username/${CONDA_PATH}/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2>             
/dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/username/${CONDA_PATH}/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/username/${CONDA_PATH}/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/username/${CONDA_PATH}/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```