# How to make your default path as base for anaconda?

Tags: miniconda, anaconda3

I have been using anaconda(in which most things are preinstalled) for a while now but recently switch to miniconda. atm whenever I need to run miniconda I have to set the source as **source ~/miniconda3/bin/activate** then I would see Base in my path and conda commands works otherwise conda command does not work. Can you please guide me on how to set my source as default on mac?

Comment: hi, perhaps might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67395283/switch-between-anaconda-and-miniconda-miniforge